# How to run GIMP on Ubuntu 16.04 (install from flatpak)?

Tags: gimp, flatpak

I install GIMP as shown in https://www.gimp.org/downloads/ by run the command in terminal

```
flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref
```

Output

```
This application depends on runtimes from:
  https://dl.flathub.org/repo/
Configure this as new remote 'flathub' [y/n]: y
Installing: org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable
Required runtime for org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable (org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.24) is not installed, searching...
Found in remote flathub, do you want to install it? [y/n]: y
Installing: org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.24 from flathub
[####################] 10 delta parts, 72 loose fetched; 196650 KiB transferred 
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform.ffmpeg/x86_64/1.6 from flathub
[####################] 1 delta parts, 2 loose fetched; 2649 KiB transferred in 9
Installing: org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Ambiance/x86_64/3.22 from flathub
[####################] 1 delta parts, 1 loose fetched; 292 KiB transferred in 5 
Installing: org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.24 from flathub
[####################] 4 metadata, 1 content objects fetched; 14 KiB transferred
Installing: org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable from flathub
[####################] 2 delta parts, 11 loose fetched; 40337 KiB transferred in
Installing: org.gimp.GIMP.Locale/x86_64/stable from flathub
[####################] 3 metadata, 1 content objects fetched; 6 KiB transferred
```

Then I tried again, it shown that GIMP is installed

```
error: App org.gimp.GIMP, branch stable is already installed
```

Now, I want to run GIMP, but I don't know how to start GIMP. I cannot find GIMP anywhere.

Tried to use terminal

```
gimp
zsh: command not found: gimp
```

Then, I use "Search your computer" (top left icon on desktop) and I cannot find GIMP anywhere.

**So, where is flatpak install GIMP ?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Type in terminal

```
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP
```

Then it will open GIMP

Comment: Why terminal to open an app?

Comment: coz it's linux ! :D :D

Comment: @Haha TTpro Is it possible to exclude `org.gimp.GIMP.Manual` from installation?

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and run the command:

`sudo apt install flatpak`

This should install the necessary items for the unwrapping of Gimp.
Then type in:

`flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref`

This should allow you to download and install Gimp into your computer.

Then run:
`flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP`

It should now be running.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to install GIMP from a Flatpack package instead of installing the native GIMP snap package? To install the latest version of GIMP in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install gimp
```

If you need to have full access to external media (such as USB flash drive, SD/MicroSD card, additional mounted hard drive and so on), run the following command:

```
sudo snap connect gimp:removable-media
```

You can also install the latest version of GIMP (v2.10) from the Ubuntu Software app by selecting the GIMP snap package which is called GIMP in Ubuntu Software or in Ubuntu 18.10 and later you can install GIMP (v2.10) using apt with `sudo apt install gimp`

[image]

`snapd` autoupdates installed snap packages by default.

Comment: because GIMP official site suggest to install from flatpak

Comment: @HahaTTpro It would be better to install the latest version of GIMP from the snap package or else from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories with `sudo apt install gimp` and either way GIMP will receive automatic updates.

Comment: @karel the snap does not provide 2.10 yet.

Comment: Also because depending on your linux version you might not find it in the repo. This was my case. I can't install 2.10 in 16.04. Also, quit answering things that question the choice of the person who is asking, they have heir reasons...

Comment: The "best" way to install applications is through a trusted source that follows best practices, particularly with regard to security. This may in fact be Flatpak in this case in other cases it may be from your distro. If you're specifically interested in the latest version and are in a position to disregard any stability and hardening steps, then build from source or follow the developers instructions on the most appropriate means.

Comment: I might also add that the GIMP version in the question GIMP (v2.10) can also be installed by apt in Ubuntu 18.10 and later.

Answer (score 1):

First install the whole flatpak framework :

https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/

Then go to Gimp's download page https://www.gimp.org/downloads/ or to Flathub app' store https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gimp.GIMP

Gimp 2.10 has been « snap-ified » since but lacks localizations / translations ( as most snap packages do - which is not ok in a LTS context… )

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to install gimp from the repository universe.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only in persistent live Ubuntu

sudo apt update                   # update information of available packages
sudo apt install gimp             # install gimp
```

Then you get a version that is tested and polished for Ubuntu. Only if this version cannot do what you want, you should look for a new version, because it might be more difficult to install, and there may be problems running it.

Comment: Thanks you for answer but I asked for how to run on flatpak.  Because GIMP dev  suggest to install on Flatpak, prehaps it is better maintained.

Comment: I suggest that you ask the developer/maintainer of the Flatpak `gimp` how to install from it.